# simple xAxis granularity setting in iOS Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, charts

i have been experimenting with the charts framework and things seems to be running as expected except the behavior of the xAxis.granularity setting.

```
barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"])
barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

when i set granularity to 2 or above, i get the expected behavior of xAxis label spread out by the value i specified. (the 3 images are for a granularity of 2,3,4)

[image: granularity = 2]

[image: granularity = 3]

[image: granularity = 4]

but when i set granularity = 1 expecting a label under every barchart, i get this

[image: granularity = 1]

what am i missing ? or is there another setting to force a label at every point ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting

```
setLabelCount(12, force: true) // replace 12 with your data.count
```

Comment: But this is not giving smooth translation and scale.. labels are fixed

Comment: This method is for predefine the label count. Please check any scaling method is available in the package. @Rajneesh071